# Corda Kubernetes Deployment on RHEL

Tags: corda

We are trying to deploy Corda network by using Kubernetes. While exploring, we just released that the document is based on cloud environment. Do we have any playbook for on prime deployment ?
https://solutions.corda.net/deployment/kubernetes/prerequisites.html

OS:RHEL 7.6

Comment: Hi are you trying to locally deploy Corda network or you are talking about CENM Corda network?

Answer (score 0):

Dinesh as of now on-prem deployments would be something which you will have to either figure out on your own, or wait a bit for the support for local installations, using for example minikube. Keep a watch on the upcoming releases to check on this release update.

Comment: for now we are using https://github.com/corda/corda-kubernetes-deployment. However facing below issues,

`Error from server (Invalid): error when creating "/root/Kubernetes/corda-kubernetes-deployment/helm/output/corda/templates/volume-CordaBridge.yml": PersistentVolume "corda-node-1-bridge-pv-volume" is invalid: spec: Required value: must specify a volume type`

Any solution; we are using single VM with RHEL

Comment: Ok as I mentioned above, on-prem deployment is on the roadmap and you will have to wait for some time for it to release.

Comment: There is a misconfiguration. You have not enabled either azureFile.enabled =true or awsEBS.enabled = true. One of them has to be true depending on which cloud you are deploying to. This error only happens if you have set both to false. Hope that helps.